# Sendgrid API curl request

Tags: sendgrid-api-v3

I am trying to test the SendGrid API using curl.  I have tested the JSON portion using the JSON Online Validator so I know it right.  But the call keeps erroring.  I am trying to run it from the Windows 10 Command Line.  Here is my code and the error:

```
c:\windows\system32\curl --request POST --url "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send" --header "Authorization: Bearer [myauthcode]" --header "Content-Type: application/json" { "personalizations": [{ "to": [{"email": "rweiser@polylutions.com" }],"cc": [{"email": "rweiser@thinktrg.com"}]}],"from": {"email": "rick@realweiser.com" },"subject": "Testing Sendgrid", "content": [{ "type": "text/plain", "value": "test email" }]}
{"errors":[{"message":"Bad Request","field":null,"help":null}]}curl: (3) unmatched brace in URL position 1:
{
 ^
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help,

Rick

Answer (score 3):

You're supposed to pass the data as --data so try this:

see if that works

```bash
curl -X POST https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send --header "Authorization: Bearer [myauthcode]" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{ "personalizations": [{ "to": [{"email": "rweiser@polylutions.com" }],"cc": [{"email": "rweiser@thinktrg.com"}]}],"from": {"email": "rick@realweiser.com" },"subject": "Testing Sendgrid", "content": [{ "type": "text/plain", "value": "test email" }]}'
```

Comment: I still get an error but its different now. 
{"errors":[{"message":"Bad Request","field":null,"help":null}]}curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (3) bad range specification in URL position 2:
[{
 ^

Comment: try to see if edited one works

Comment: {"errors":[{"message":"Bad Request","field":null,"help":null}]}curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (3) bad range specification in URL position 2:
[{
 ^

Comment: can you run this and tell me if you get errors: curl https://reqbin.com/echo

Comment: d:\Scripts> curl reqbin.com/echo  So I didn't get a anything but it didn't error either.

Comment: try the updated post

Comment: {"errors":[{"message":"Bad Request","field":null,"help":null}]}curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (3) bad range specification in URL position 2:
[{to:

Comment: Thats weird im able to run the command just fine on my end but im using Mac - what language are you writing code in - maybe try doing the CURL in actual code?

Comment: Its even matching their recommendation in the documentation as well so im not sure why it wouldnt work https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/mail-send/mail-send

Comment: I am simply running it from the Windows command line.   Do I need to upgrade curl?

Comment: what version are you on?

Comment: also try running your exact curl command on this website and see what it gives:  https://reqbin.com/req/c-g95rmxs0/curl-for-windows

Comment: I had to change my from address to my account email and it worked on the site.  the same code does not work on my Win10 PC.  I will update curl, I have an older version on my pc.

Comment: Yes the from address must match but if it doesn't the response error would specify that. Good luck

Comment: I did not have any luck sending from within a CMD prompt.  I was able to run the command via reqbin.com. I did get the emails.  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Can anyone else help with this?

Comment: have you updated your curl - what version of curl are you running?

Comment: doing some reading i found this Windows version of curl seems a bit different from Unix version of curl which is shown in the examples at the API site.

Comment: Try to mask double quotes with backslash https://superuser.com/questions/1016710/how-to-make-a-curl-post-call-in-windows

Answer (score 1):

put your --data string in a text file.

reference that text file from your Windows 10 curl cmd

then you don't need to escape the dbl quotes in the data string

```bash
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer SG.REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_API_KEY" -d @D:\sendgrid_data.txt https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send
```

source: [suggested solution by superuser jonno](https://superuser.com/a/1016713/27605)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first I had to escape all of the double quotes in the --data section with .  To use HTML codes like 
 or

...

, I need to run the command from powershell.